# Testng 6.9.6 is missing OSGi Headers

Tags: osgi, testng, pax-exam

I've used the testng 6.9.6 for integrate with pax-exam. however I've noticed that OSGi headers are missing from the testng 6.9.6 jar's Manifest file. [1]. So had to switched to 6.9.4 version. Any idea why it's not there in 6.9.6?

[1]. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We changed build tool and forgot the osgi configuration. 
It should be fixed now: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/759

Comment: Thanks juherr. Which means this will be fixed in 6.9.7?